# unable to set blog template

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to make custom template for my blog page i have used wordress tidythemes ( https://github.com/tidythemes/blankslate ) for that what issue i am having.

how can i make wordpress to use custom template for my blogs.

1: i created page name blogs to show all blogs , now when i edit this page i can not see option to set teamplate for it

2: i can see that option in page list quick setting but it seems not working it show data from some hometemplate not what i set in quick edit.

i there way to force some template file for all blogs

Answer (score 0):

It'll be tough to say without actually seeing your code, but chances are good the reason you don't see the page template dropdown when editing your "Blog" page is because you don't have any templates defined.

To create a custom page template:

1) Create a new file in the root of your theme and call it `template-blog.php`.

2) In that file, add the following lines of code:

```
<?php
/*
/* Template Name: Blog
/*
*/?>
```

Once you've taken those steps, check your WordPress "Blog" page again. The "Page Template" dropdown should now appear, displaying an option called "Blog" that you can select.

For more detail around custom page templates and template hierarchies, take a look at the [WordPress Theme Handbook.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

Comment: yeah i did like that but in can not see option to chnage page template , can you tell why so